# http Web Request gives 500 server error?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

So i Tried using this code to send data to API for creating a new account but it crashed and gave a 500 server error.

```
var Account= new Account();
Account.name = "Test Name";

//Serialize
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Account);


WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.example.com/profiles/1");
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Method = "POST";

    using (streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            using (httpWebResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                var jsonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

So then i tried the example of the msdn website:

```
             // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("https://api.example.com/profiles/1");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (json);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close ();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
```

And the code from  the msdn gave the same error.

Then i tried Rest Easy plugin and posted data to the the api and that worked fine and did not give any errors and created the account.

What could be wrong with this? am i doing something wrong or missing? also the first code worked fine for using the Method PATCH

Comment: First of all, your Url should include the scheme: http or whatever...

Comment: Trace the request with fiddler or wireshark and make sure it matches.